# "Assignment to read-only property" error while setting up Core Bluetooth Peripheral Manager Services and Characteristics

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm following the Apple Core Bluetooth programming guide, trying to set up a peripheralManager which will advertise certain data. I've written the following code based on the guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW1

```
 _peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];
CBUUID *myConnectUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"277860A8-9941-465B-9E75-F77F935299E7"];
CBUUID *advertiseUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"C223B374-18FF-4D0B-8B46-B7CEC9C85077"];

_myCharacteristic =
[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:advertiseUUID
                                   properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
                                        value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

_myService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:myConnectUUID primary:YES];
_myService.characteristics = @[_myCharacteristic];
[_peripheralManager addService:_myService];
```

However, on the line

```
_myService.characteristics = @[_myCharacteristic];
```

I get an Xcode error which says "assignment to read-only property." I'm not sure what the issue is, since I directly followed the instructions, and am initializing the service/characteristic correctly. Does anyone have any advice?

Declaration of _myservice in .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBService *myService;
```

Comment: error is clear readonly means it can't be assigned

Comment: Don't use the Swift tag when your code is clearly Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBService *myService;
```

You have declared `_myService` as a CBService, so it is not mutable as far as the compiler knows. Thus, for `_myService`, `characteristics` is not assignable.

You should have written

```
CBMutableService* service = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:myConnectUUID primary:YES];
service.characteristics = @[_myCharacteristic];
_myService = service;
```

Comment: I typed it out wrong in the post; in my actual code I am using an array, but still getting the error I described

Comment: Okay, fixed my answer. The problem must lie in your declaration of `_myService` (not shown in your question).

Comment: How should I declare it so its mutable? I mean, in the developer guide it looks like it can be done

Comment: You don't. You use a local.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but could you elaborate on that? Even if I declare myService locally it would still have to be declared as a CBService, right?

Comment: Do you understand about Objective-C having immutable class / mutable subclass pairs? If not, might help to read my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_immutable_and_mutable